# How to set values in a 2D array? (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

I'm making a method that takes 2 inputs, one is int[][], the other is int. I need to store that int value as the "row" of the int array. For example if I input (int[][] array, int 3493), I need the row to be {3 4 9 3}. This is basically like the 2048 games, as I need to be able to manipulate the array later. I do not know the proper syntax for this, however. Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you could see a tutorial on arrays ? (the one on the Java official website is pretty concise and clear). I mean if you don't know the "proper" syntax, you should read a tutorial.

Comment: "The row"? Which one? And if there is only one, why are you using a 2D array?

Comment: @cupfeak I posted my answer hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As An Sample**, suppose `x = new int[3][4]`, `x[0]`, `x[1]`, and `x[2]` are one-dimensional
arrays and each contains four elements, as shown in the figure `x.length` is `3`, and
`x[0].length`, `x[1].length`, and `x[2].length` are `4`

[image]

As you see you need **two for loops** to go through the array.

> **1**. for traversing the row one by one
>
> **2**. when you are in each row traversing each column one by one

for example:

[image]